# After setting the minifyEnabled as true I'm getting the following error

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, proguard, firebase-authentication

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.pharmaz.partner, PID: 26775
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.pharmaz.partner/in.pharmaz.partner.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzald cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzald cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadh.zzN(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzOj(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadg.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at in.pharmaz.partner.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The `SplashScreenActivity` line number 38 is:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

My ProGuard rules contain:

```
-keep class com.google.** {*;}
```

I tried searching everywhere, found nothing.

My `build.gradle`:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        proguardFile 'C:/Users/vikas/Desktop/phzVendor/phzandvendor/app/proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        proguardFile 'C:/Users/vikas/Desktop/phzVendor/phzandvendor/app/proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: main exception is - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzald cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo

Comment: Please Post you build.gradle file

Comment: I know it, but the thing is its working when minifyEnabled is false. I think proguard is obfuscating something, which is leading this error. I dont know what rules i have to write to avoid that.

Comment: Yes See here same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883160/firebaseauth-classcastexception

Comment: Thanks! It Worked. I added -keepattributes Signature in proguard rules file.

Answer (score 3):

Whe you set `minifyEnabled` as `true` it means proguard start works.
You need to provide proper proguard configs for each lib and the app.

For the firebase you could find configs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273929/what-proguard-configuration-do-i-need-for-firebase-on-android) or in [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)

And [here is](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets) a project that collects many usefull snippets for proguard config.