# Firebase Email and Password Authentication with android - User sign up

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently created a simple sign up page for my application, the page takes the two values of email and password, checks they are valid then passes them into a firebase function to create the user. The values are being passed correctly, however, I always get the message saying "Registration Failed". The firebase connection is active and I have allowed for users to sign up using email and password authenication.

I feel it is an issue with my `build.gradle` files, maybe having the wrong dependencies, however, I am new to Firebase and can't figure this out.

Below is my Register form, build.gradle files and a console log of the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Register Form**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class RegisterPage extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText userEmail,userPassword;
private Button regButton;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);
    setUpUIViews();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (validate()){

                //Upload Data to the database

                String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String user_password = 
 userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email,user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                       if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       startActivity(new Intent(RegisterPage.this,MainActivity.class));
                    }



                   else {

                          // FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException)task.getException();
                      // Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this,"Failed Registation: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                   }
                });
            }

        }
    });

}


private void setUpUIViews(){

    userEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email_Register);
    userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password_Register);
    regButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Register_btn);
}

private Boolean validate(){

    Boolean result = false;

    String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = userPassword.getText().toString();

    if (email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter all your details correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else {

        result = true;


    }

    return result;

}


}
```

**Build.Gradle (project)**
buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    //added maven
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build.Gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bradwaterhouse.discovernottingham"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//added in
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Console log**

This is the error message I get if i replace the "login failed" text in the else loop.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.bradwaterhouse.discovernottingham, PID: 4473
              java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException
                  at com.example.bradwaterhouse.discovernottingham.RegisterPage$1$1.onComplete(RegisterPage.java:59)
                  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: what is ur line number `RegisterPage.java:59` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883160/firebaseauth-classcastexception

Comment: FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException)task.getException();
                          Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this,"Failed Registation: 
    "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: It's the error check function inside the else statment.

Comment: @BradWaterhouse update all firebase dependencies to 11.8.0 `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'`

Comment: @PeterHaddad, should I change the compile one to that version as well?

Comment: just remove the compile one it is not needed

Comment: @PeterHaddad still getting registration failed.

Comment: @PeterHaddad - I don't understand where this code needs to be added? inside the else statement?

Comment: is it working after commenting out firebaseauthexception line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with OP, the error was:

> I/error is: An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 248549959996 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting console.developers.google.com/… then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. ]

To solve it he had to enable the google identity toolkit api.

Also it is better to add the below to be able to know what exactly the problem is:

Add this in your else, you will get the error more clearer:

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "User Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or add it in `Log`:

```
Log.i("error is :", task.getException().getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid exception like below :-

```
    if (ex instanceof FirebaseAuthException) {
        FirebaseAuthError error = FirebaseAuthError.fromException((FirebaseAuthException) ex);
        // TODO
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
```